# Counter "errors" is counting every single time the while loop runs instead of errors

Tags: java

I'm trying to have a counter that counts the number of errors that the program is running into while scanning a `.txt` document.

I've tried just using else, and then I tried using: `else if (! (token.equalsIgnoreCase("BB") || ...)` and `else if (! (token.equalsIgnoreCase("BB") && ...)`. None of those are working.

```
  while(inFile.hasNextLine())
  {
    token = inFile.nextLine(); 
    //Scanning token
    if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("BB"))
    {
      numBoys ++;
      numFamilies ++;
    }
    else if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("GG"))
    {
      numGirls ++;
      numFamilies ++;
    }
    else if ((token.equalsIgnoreCase("GB")) || (token.equalsIgnoreCase("BG")))
    {
      numBoth ++;
      numFamilies ++;
    }
    else
    {
      errors ++; //broken
    }
  }
```

The counter "error" should only go up when token is not equal to "BB", "GG", "GB", and "BG". However, it is counting every time the while loop runs.

Comment: There is probably a newline or something in token as well making it not match. Try using `token.toUpperCase().startsWith()` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine. The error is probably in understanding what in the data constitutes a line, for example if the lines end with CR+LF is it possible .nextline() gets one line for CR and one line for LF.

Try counting the lines and see if it corresponds to the answer you expect.

```
int lines = 0;
while(inFile.hasNextLine())
  {
    token = inFile.nextLine(); 
    lines++ ;
  }
System.out.print(lines);
```

Comment: Ohhh ok. I see that now. Thank you. What was going on was that my (.txt) files had a blank enter/line between every combination of B and G. So my error counter was counting every blank line between them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a snippet from (.txt) file here for better help. Your conditional statements seem right, though.

Actually what could be happening is, there could be some **newlinecharacter (\n)** in each line due to which the `string.equalsIgnoreCase()` method is not giving you the desired result.

try
`token.toUpperCase().contains("YOURSTRING")`
instead of 
`token.equalsIgnoreCase("YOURSTRING")`

Comment: The (.txt) file is literally just: BB

GB

GB

BG

GG

GB

GB

GB

GB

GG. (When enter's between each)

Comment: Then yes, newline character i.e. **\n** is the culprit here.

See, when the method `token.equalsIgnoreCase()` is called, the token's actual string value at that moment is not, "BB", its actually "BB\n".

So, literal comparison "BB\n" is not equal to "BB".

To make your code work, You'd either have to remove "\n".

Like `token.replaceAll("\n", "").equalsIgnoreCase("BB")`

or you could try 
 
`token.toUpperCase().contains("BB")`

as suggested in the answer.